# Sprout reports options can't find form fields

Tags: plugin-sproutreports

I'm getting an error on my options template when I run the report, the sprout from can't find the form fields template and I get this error

> Unable to find the template “_includes/forms” in
>   "__string_template__1e75d07f7afb92cfc030941cdd0c214a5067c25743f143e36dcfc3dd77a06f62"
>   at line 1.

When I remove the import I get this error

> Variable "forms" does not exist in
>   "__string_template__68fd366166a1d3cc8e58752e3634a261ca9faaa526e284d487e82cc2434316c9"
>   at line 2.

Here is my options.twig

```
{% import '_includes/forms' as forms %}

{% set limitByDateRange = settings.limitByDateRange ?? false %}

{{ forms.lightswitchField({
    label: 'Filter By Date Range'|t,
    name: 'limitByDateRange',
    on: limitByDateRange,
    value: 1,
    toggle: 'toggle-dateRangeFields',
    first: true
}) }}

<div id="toggle-dateRangeFields" class="{% if not limitByDateRange %}hidden{% endif %}">
    {{ forms.date({
        label: 'Start Date'|t,
        id: 'datetimeStartDate',
        name: 'datetimeStartDate',
        value: settings.datetimeStartDate is defined ? settings.datetimeStartDate : now|date_modify('-1 month')
    }) }}

    <p style="display: inline-block;margin: 0 5px;">to</p>

    {{ forms.date({
        label: 'End Date'|t,
        id: 'datetimeEndDate',
        name: 'datetimeEndDate',
        value: settings.datetimeEndDate is defined ? settings.datetimeEndDate : now
    }) }}
</div>

{%- js %}
    $('#options-datetimeStartDate-date').datepicker($.extend({
        defaultDate: new Date({{ now.year }}, {{ now.month-1 }}, {{ now.day }})
    }, Craft.datepickerOptions));

    $('#options-datetimeEndDate-date').datepicker($.extend({
        defaultDate: new Date({{ now.year }}, {{ now.month }}, {{ now.day }})
    }, Craft.datepickerOptions));

    $('#modify-options-panel').attr('style', null);
{%- endjs %}
```

I also already tried to copy the examples templates from the plugin folder and I get the same error. 
Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong? I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Can you confirm what version of Craft and Sprout Reports you are using? I believe this issue was introduced in Craft CMS v3.3.7 and solved updating to Sprout Reports v1.2.8.

Comment: Hi Ben thanks for your reply, I'm using Craft CMS 3.3.1.2 and Sprout Reports 1.2.7

Answer (score 2):

As Ben Parizek pointed out in the comments this was a bug that was fixed on Sprout Reports 1.2.8.

I couldn't see Sprout Reports update because my Craft CMS installation was below v3.3.7, I updated Craft CMS and then updated Sprout Forms to v1.2.8 which fixed the bug.